# why predict () function in R does not give prediction?

Tags: r, predict, rpart

My training dataset has 40000 rows. After I fit a CART model using

`fit<-rpart(y~x,method="class")`

I was trying to use

`predict(fit,data.frame(new_x),family="response")`

The error message is:

```
Warning message:
`'newdata' had 100 rows but variable(s) found have 40000 rows.`
```

Besides, I checked the `"predicted value`", they are actually fitted value using training `x`. Anyone knows the reason?

Comment: Looking at `?predict.rpart`, perhaps `type = "class"` instead of `family="response"`?

Comment: More generally, unless you put some effort into providing a reproducible example (code that we can copy+paste and run) there might not be much we can do.

Comment: I believe the dataframe with the new data needs to contain a variable `x`. Try `predict(fit,data.frame(x=new_x))`. I don't know which package you are using and cannot say anything about the `family` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Brilliant, Roland got it.  I had the same problem but solved it when I changed

```
data.frame(x=)
```

to

```
data.frame (variablename=)
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides, If using `predict()` with objects created by functions in the package `np`, always name both your training variables and `newdata=` variables x and y.

Other variable names do not work properly.